# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to run sample java application with selenium. I installed chrome driver and selenium web driver also. But i am getting an error chrome failed to start.I am using Selenium for automating the tests.

The below is the error getting for my eclipse ide.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 26797
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 206 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'RAVIII', ip: '192.168.11.60', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Ps. please don't provide your IP-Adress to users in future.

Comment: plz provide script which is executed